# Removing a stripped screw from laptop

Tags: laptop, screws

I damaged the head of a screw in my laptop and now I can't get it out.

What's the best way to remove it?

Soldering it to something? Or is there any other way?

Comment: What does the damage to the head of the screw look like?

Comment: It's just really worn out.

Comment: Also related: [How to remove screws with stripped heads?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/10451)

Answer (score 2):

Either cut a notch in the screw with a dremel or use a [screw extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_extractor). You can also try to get a grip with a small flat head screwdriver. Often, it's too stripped to get a phillips screwdriver to grip, but a flat head will grip.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and come back to say if it worked, thanks!

Comment: @t.pimentel did it work?